# @XmlTransient not working for Json

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I am creating a simple API using Jersey Jax-Rs. I am using @XmlTransient to ignore the POJO being displayed in the output for a 1-to-many relationship. It works fine for XML output but the POJO gets displayed while outputting JSON. Do I need to add any dependency?

I am using the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: Use `jersey-media-json-jackson` instead (and remove the other one).

Comment: @PaulSamsotha thanks for the solution. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using json-media-json-binding.jar , There is an annotation "@JsonbTransient" which helped me achieve this.